# WFi Network Discovery in Windows 10/11

Tags: wifi, windows-10, discovery

If you have a known WiFi AP, that you have connected to previously, and you know is always on, is it possible to not discover other WiFi networks and only connect to the known trusted WiFi network.  I don't see the point of needing to constantly see other networks that I am not interested in.  My "good" AP sometimes is delayed in showing up on the taskbar list of available networks.  I tried setting up a network profile for the network with a shortcut, but it didn't help me connect to the AP any faster.  I am just trying work efficiently and question the status quo.  I know about having a connection configured to always connect when available, but this doesn't always result in a fast connection when the AP isn't announced or for some reason doesn't show up for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to background scanning? If so, you can set the startup of the service "WLAN AutoConfig" to manual and this should achieve that.